# Failing to install moodle plugin

Tags: plugins, moodle

I am new to moodle I  created a new plugin and now I am trying to install it.

I get this error:

Plugin "admin_report" is installed in incorrect location "$CFG->dirroot/admin/tool/bbb", expected location is ""

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure that your plugin's version.php correctly declares the component - in this case (based on your install location) it would be:

```
$version->component = "tool_bbb";
```

See https://docs.moodle.org/dev/version.php for more details.